# Safari can't install this extension

Tags: safari-extension

Hi Friends i developed a safari extension and also able to build it.
but when i am trying to install it folloing error occurs:
 "Safari can't install this extension. An error occured while installing this extension"
 i have a valid safari developer certificate and it is installed on my machine.
it is simple a helloworld extension nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

hi friends i found the solution. priviously my development folder name was *MySafaraiExtension* so it was unable to install and solution is that you have to name your developement folder to *MySafariExtension.safariextension*.